# (*b)[0] vs *b[0] - Arrays and pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm working through toy problems to understand the differences between pointers and arrays in C and I've stumbled upon something I'm not yet able to grok or find an answer to.

I have the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5,6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    int (*b)[3];

    b = a;

    printf("%d %d %d\n", (*b)[0], (*b)[1], (*b)[2]);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", *b[0], *b[1], *b[2]);

    b++;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", (*b)[0], (*b)[1], (*b)[2]);

    b++;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", (*b)[0], (*b)[1], (*b)[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

And when I compile and run it I get this:

```
me@mac: clang -g q.c -o q.o                                                                     
me@mac: ./q.o
1 2 3
1 4 7
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

My question is what's the difference between `(*b)[0]` and `*b[0]`? It appears that the former is of type `int *` while the latter is of type `int *[3]`. How to interpret the operators `*[]()` to grok this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int (*b)[3];` is an *array pointer*, a special kind of pointer that can point to a whole array and not just to the first element. Not to be confused with `int *b[3]` which is an array of 3 pointers and not present in your code.

`b=a` sets b to point to the first element in the 2D array `a`, which is a 1D array.

When you dereference an array pointer, you get the array. And when an array is used in an expression, it "decays" into a pointer to the first element, which explains the first printf line.

If you write `*b[0]`, then [] has higher operator precedence than *, so it means "give me array number 0, it will decay into a pointer to the first element, give me the contents of that element".

For any pointer type, array pointers included, pointer increments of `b` follow the rules of pointer arithmetic: increase the address so that the pointer points at the next adjacent item of pointed-at-type in memory. That is, increase the address with `sizeof(*b)` bytes, which will be `3*sizeof(int)` in this example.

Comment: ahh, I should have a known once I wrote operators to think of operator precedence. Your answer clears things up for me.

Answer (score 2):

This only applies to two-dimensional arrays, not to any random pointers.

When using `(*b)[1]` the dereferencing is done first and then the indexing, so it actually means `b[0][1]` and you are getting values from the first array.

If you use `*b[1]` it is the same as `*(b[1])`. The indexing operator will be handled first and the the dereferencing, so you get `b[1][0]`.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is what is the difference between (*b)[0] and *b[0]?

`int (*b)[3] ;`  is pointer to one dimensional array of size 3  In this  case it  first dereference the pointer and then do index access because of `()`.

`*b[3]`  is  array of 3 pointers, In this case first do index access because of [ ];

because of that when you doing

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", (*b)[0], (*b)[1], (*b)[2]);

printf("%d %d %d\n", *b[0], *b[1], *b[2]);
```

in first `printf` it is printing element of first one dimensional array in second `printf` it is pointing to first element of each row.

after  `b++` in first case pointing to second array and second `printf`  it is pointing to second element of each row.

Answer (score 0):

`(*b)[0]` first dereference the pointer and then do index access. It is equivalent to `*((*b)+(0))`.

`*b[0]` first do index access and then dereference the pointer. It is equivalent to `**((b)+(0))`.

Adding zero means virtually nothing, so both of them are equivalent to `**b` with type `int`, so there are virtually no difference.

Answer (score 0):

`b` is a pointer to an array of `3` `int`s. In the assignment

```
b = a;
```

`a` will decay to pointer to its first element. Since `a` is an array of arrays, its first element is and array of `3` `int`s. Therefore, the above statement is equivalent to

```
b = &a[0];
```

So, `b` is pointing to array `a[0]`. The elements of array `a[0]` can be accessed by using index `a[0][i]`. In pointer arithmetic  equivalent it is  `*(*(a + 0) + i)` =  `*(*(a) + i)` = `*(*a + i)` = `(*a)[i]`.
In the expression `(*a)[i]` the type of `a` after conversion is `int (*)[3]` which is also the type of `b`. Therefore, array `a[0]` can also be accessed by using `(*b)[i]`.
So, the statement

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", (*b)[0], (*b)[1], (*b)[2]);
```

is equivalent to

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", (*a)[0], (*a)[1], (*a)[2]);
```

or

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", a[0][0], a[0][1], a[0][2]);
```

Now look at `*b[0]`. As per operator precedence rule, `*b[0]` is equivalent to `*(b[0])`. Simply `b[0]` is representing array `a[0]` as discussed above and array converted to pointer to its first element when used in an expression, with some exception there, `b[0]` is actually a pointer to element `a[0][0]` in the expression `*(b[0])`. `*` out of `()` dereferencing this pointer and giving the value present at `&a[0][0]`. Similarly, `*b[1]` and `*b[2]` are giving the elements at the address `&a[1][0]` and `&a[2][0]`.
Therefore, the statement

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", *b[0], *b[1], *b[2]);
```

is equivalent to

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", *a[0], *a[1], *a[2]);
```

or

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", &a[0][0], &a[0][1], &[0][2]);
```

This results in a conclusion that both `(*b)[0]` and `*b[0]` are of same type, `int`.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but answers seem to miss some important points.

> what is the difference between (*b)[0] and *b[0]?

provided that *b* is a pointer arrays of 3 int, and points to *a*.

```
int (*b)[3] = a; // int a[3][3]
```

to avoid some confusion, let say that *a* and *b* are

```
int a[X][Y];     // in your example, X=Y=3
int (*b)[Y] = a; // this line probably gives some clue about what b is
```

This is a matter of [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). `[]` takes precedence over `*`, meaning that

- if you don't put the parents to `*b[0]`, `b[0]` is evaluated first and yields a `int [Y]`, the first `[Y]` array of `[X][Y]`, then `*` is applied and decays (dereferences) into an `int`, the first int of that array of `Y`.
  Result (or target) is the *int* in `a[0][0]`.
- with the parents, `(*b)[0]`, `*b` is evaluated first yielding a `int [Y]`, the first one, then the `[0]` gives the first *int* of that `[Y]`.
  Result (or target) is the *int* in `a[0][0]`. Again... really?

**But** the two `[0]` are not the same thing! The confusion comes from both the `*` and `[0]` yield to the first element, however the order of evaluation is different in both cases.